# String to ArrayBuffer weird endianness behavior

Tags: javascript, endianness, arraybuffer

I wanted to pass char values from a string to an ArrayBuffer offset by several bytes. So I wrote this function which does exactly that. However I stumbled across something odd (or that I couldn't understand). These two function produce exactly identical results.

```
function setString(dv, off, str) {
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        dv.setUint16(i * 2 + off, str.charCodeAt(i), false);
    }
}

function setStringWhy(dv, off, str) {
    for(var i = off; i < str.length + off; i++) {
        dv.setUint16(i * 2, str.charCodeAt(i - off), true);
    }
}
```

Why does offsetting by one byte more and using different endiannes result in the same?

**EDIT:**

A snippet of how I'm trying to use these functions

```
var data = new ArrayBuffer(2 + 7*2);
var dv = new DataView(data);
dv.setUint16(0, 0x0010, false);
var color = '#abcdef';
setString(dv, 2, color);
console.log( new Uint8Array( data.slice(2, 7*2 + 2) ));
console.log( new Uint16Array( data.slice(2, 7*2 + 2) ));
console.log( String.fromCharCode.apply( null, new Uint16Array( data.slice(2, 7*2 + 2) )) );
```

Apparently produces

```
Uint8Array [ 0, 35, 0, 97, 0, 98, 0, 99, 0, 100, 0, 101, 0, 102 ]
Uint16Array [ 8960, 24832, 25088, 25344, 25600, 25856, 26112 ]
⌀愀戀挀搀攀昀
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but shouldn't these Uint16Array values be ex. 0x0035 instead of 0x3500 ?

**Solution:**

```
var getString16 = function(dv, beg, end) {
    var c = [];
    for(var i = beg; i < end; i += 2) {
        c.push(dv.getUint16(i, false));
    }
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, c);
}


var setString16 = function(dv, off, str) {
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        dv.setUint16(i * 2 + off, str.charCodeAt(i), false);
    }
}

// Usage example
var data = new ArrayBuffer(2 + 7*2);
var dv = new DataView(data);
dv.setUint8(0, 0x10, false);
var color = '#abcdef';
setString16(dv, 1, color);
```

Comment: It definitely should not produce the same result in all cases. Please show us how you are calling the functions (with which example values).

Comment: Why do you think the second code is "*offsetting by one byte more*"?

Comment: Uh, if I execute your example code with `setStringWhy` instead of `setString`, I'm getting "*`Uncaught RangeError: Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView`*" which is obviously not the same result.

Comment: What's that `offset` of 2 and the slicing good for?

Comment: "*shouldn't these Uint16Array values be ex. 0x0035 instead of 0x3500?*" - not on a little endian machine, no. That's exactly why you need `DataView` when you want to control the endianness.

Comment: Well, that's why I'm using dv.setUint16(..., false). That should mean it's stored as big-endian. Right?

Comment: Yes, and it *is* stored big-endian, as your bytewise logging (with `Uint8Array`) demonstrates. But that doesn't keep `Uint16Array` from interpreting that data little-endian - you cannot specify your own endianness there. Notice that endianness is a property of the conversion between bytes and numbers, not of the memory itself.

Comment: I never realized that. So instead of logging the array as it is I should first `getUint16` as big-endian? That would actually explain why `DataView` exists.

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Or use `Uint16Array` all over the place to have unknown but consistent endianness.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Actually I can't use Uint16Array everywhere as I need to send packets of multiple typed data. (ex. `[Uint16, Float32, Float32, Uint32]`) from a server to a client. Which led me to sticking to big-endian everywhere.